# Java Mail Formatting a table sent in an e-mail using CSS?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I can success you the Java Mail API to send e-mails but now I am trying to sending the contents of a ResultSet populated from a MySQL query in table formatted with borders etc, can I use CSS tags to do this? if so how?

My code is as follows:

```
public void getOutstanding() throws MessagingException {
    try {
        String outS = "SELECT period_to, type, amt, status FROM tblinstall "
                        + "WHERE status like ?";

        PreparedStatement update = toDB.prepareStatement(outS);

        email = new StringBuilder();

        email.append("<html><head><style type='text/css'>table .out {border-width:1px, "
                    + "border-color: black}</style></head>"
                    + "<body>"
                    + "<table class'out'><span style=border-color: black, border-width: 1px>");

        update.setString(1, "Outstanding");
        ResultSet results = update.executeQuery();

        while (results.next()) {
            System.out.println("in results...");
            email.append("<tr>");
            email.append("<td>");
            long period = results.getLong("period_to");
            email.append(DateConvert.fromEpoch(period));
            email.append("</td>");

            email.append("<td>");
            email.append(results.getString("type"));
            email.append("</td>");

            email.append("<td>");
            email.append(results.getString("amt"));
            email.append("</td>");

            email.append("<td>");
            email.append(results.getString("status"));
            email.append("</td>");

            email.append("<tr>");
        }

        email.append("</table></body></html>");
        sm.populateMailMessage(email.toString());
        sm.sendMail();
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        sql.printStackTrace();
    }                 
}
```

I am able to send the email but only plain text, 'sm' is an instances of SendMail as below:

```
public class SendMail {
    private Properties mailAccessCredentials;
    private Session mailSession;
    private MimeMessage mailMessage;        

    public SendMail() throws MessagingException{
        populateProperties();
    }    

    private void populateProperties() throws AddressException, MessagingException {     
        //Step1    
        System.out.println("\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
        mailAccessCredentials = System.getProperties();
        mailAccessCredentials.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // TLS Port
        mailAccessCredentials.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // Enable Authentication
        mailAccessCredentials.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // Enable StartTLS
        System.out.println("Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..");     
    }    

    public void populateMailMessage(String msg) throws MessagingException{               
        //Step2    
        System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailAccessCredentials, null);
        mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        mailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("n****@gmail.com"));

        mailMessage.setSubject("Report from Database Payments now Due");

        mailMessage.setContent(msg, "text/html");
        System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");
    }

    public void sendMail() throws MessagingException{        
        //Step3    
        System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        // Enter your correct gmail UserID and Password
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "lettingssmart@******", "****");
        transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        SendMail sm = new SendMail();
        //sm.populateMailMessage();
        sm.sendMail();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use inline css

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was trying to achieve this using this code:

Comment: email.append("<html><head><style type='text/css'>table .out {border-width:1px, "
                    + "border-color: black}</style></head>"
                    + "<body>"
                    + "<table class'out'><span style=border-color: black, border-width: 1px>");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use [inline css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) for style your table .you can't use css separatly since most email services don't support it ..try to change your email String building code to following code.

```
 email.append("<html><body>"
                    + "<table style='border:2px solid black'>");

        update.setString(1, "Outstanding");
        ResultSet results = update.executeQuery();

        while (results.next()) {
            System.out.println("in results...");
            email.append("<tr bgcolor=\"#33CC99\">");
            email.append("<td>");
            long period = results.getLong("period_to");
            email.append(DateConvert.fromEpoch(period));
            email.append("</td>");

            email.append("<td>");
            email.append(results.getString("type"));
            email.append("</td>");

            email.append("<td>");
            email.append(results.getString("amt"));
            email.append("</td>");

            email.append("<td>");
            email.append(results.getString("status"));
            email.append("</td>");

            email.append("<tr>");
        }

        email.append("</table></body></html>");
        sm.populateMailMessage(email.toString());
        sm.sendMail();
```

Comment: Thanks @fastsnail! I assume I can use other valid css properties such as padding etc? :)

Comment: @mg3np1 i guess you can. but plz check ..u can send to email, yahoo  ..etc and check does your css property works or not

Comment: @mg3np1 and also look this one http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

Comment: Is this still the way to do it on 2017?